# Git with Cygwin - not accepting userinput for Username

Tags: git, cygwin

I am trying to clone a repository which requires authentication.  With msysgit, I will get prompted for the username/password and it will clone.  However, in Cygwin (v1.7.9) I will also get prompted, but when I type it will not take my input.  I press ctrl-C to abort, and my entry is buffered and it attempts it as a command.

How can I get Cygwin to accept user input from the Git server?

Here's an example of what I see:

```
$ git clone http://gitsbx01.mycompany.com/git/qct/manifest.git
Cloning into manifest...
Username: [I type it and doesn't recognize so CTRL-C]

$ lou
bash: lou: command not found
```

Comment: It looks like a general issue not connected with git. It looks like keyboard inputs are not handled correctly in your particular Cygwin installation, however it's just my wild guess.

Comment: Are you using Cygwin git or msysgit in Cygwin, i.e. what's the output of `which git`?

Comment: I'm using Cygwin Git (1.7.5.1).  Although, if I alias to msysgit, it will accept input.  Not sure what the difference is though.

Comment: Is the bash you issued the command from run with --login and -i?  I think the -i is particularly important for your case.

Comment: It seems that the cygwin build is broken? Did you tried to update the git of the cygwin build? Additionally gig you tried also the form: `git clone http://username@gitsbx01.mycompany.com/git/qct/manifest.git` (however it is not specified in the git help)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that git bash works better on windows than cygwin + git. Maby that would help with the console io issue your having too.

Comment: git bash is the same thing as msysgit.

Comment: Yes i think  its the same git... so it must be something environmental about the way its launched.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into that myself.  I believe the code in git that prompts for the username and password is buggy; it works in the msysgit environment, but not under Cygwin.

My workaround was to set it up to work with passwordless ssh, which is more secure anyway.  If the remote system doesn't support that, you can use msysgit (Git Bash) for the few commands that require authentication (push, pull, fetch) and Cygwin for everything else.

(Or you could just do everything in msysgit, but personally I like the Cygwin environment much better.)

Beware that there are some minor differences in behavior between msysgit and cygwin git, though nothing fatal.  In msysgit, any file with a suffix of `.exe`, `.bat`, `.cmd`, etc. is implicitly treated as executable; in Cygwin they're not unless you explicitly do a `chmod +x`.

Answer (score 0):

Use '--usernamev YOURUSERNAME' at the end of your line

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that it does accept input but doesn't display the characters on the screen. If you are a flawless typer then just type the username and hit enter.